# Dimension of cokernel of direct sum of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quotient-spaces, direct-sum

Assume that operators $A,B$ and $C$ are Fredholm where operator $A:= (B, C)$  mapping from vector spaces $X \rightarrow Y \oplus Z$,
$B: X \rightarrow Y$ and $C: X \rightarrow Z$.
Now we restrict operator $B$ to a smaller domain $$B_{1}: ker(C) \rightarrow Y.$$

Is it true or not that $dim((Y \oplus Z) / Img(A)) = dim(Y / Img(B_1))$?